# Cambiar el estado de los widgets en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

Necesito que al llegar a siete caracteres, los dos widgets de abajo cambien su estado a activo. El código corre bien, pero cuando escribo los siete caracteres los de abajo no se activan. Quien me pueda corregir, gracias.

```
marco_ticket = customtkinter.CTk()
marco_ticket.geometry(f"{600}x{300}")
marco_ticket.title("Control de Pesajes Baelca")

#Función validar placa
def validar_placa():
    texto=entry_placa.get()
    if len(texto) >=7:
        entrada.configure(State="normal")
        entrada2.configure(state="normal")
    else:
        pass    
  
                    

label_placa=customtkinter.CTkLabel(marco_ticket, text="Placa :", text_font=("arial", 16))
label_placa.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
entry_placa=customtkinter.CTkEntry(marco_ticket)
entry_placa.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, padx=50)
        
        
entrada=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(marco_ticket, values=["Lleno", "Vacio", "Pesada múltiple"], state="disabled")
entrada.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=5, padx=5)
entrada.set("Lleno")

entrada2=customtkinter.CTkEntry(marco_ticket, state="disabled")
entrada2.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=5, padx=5)
validar_placa()  

marco_ticket.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que tu función la ejecutas una sola vez (abajo de entrada2). No la asocias a ningún validador, variable de control ni nada que le pueda indicar a Tkinter que la función debe ejecutarse ni en que momentos.

Una forma de lograr que la función se ejecute siempre que el usuario escribe o pega algo sería usar un validador.
Un validador es una caracteristica de Tkinter (no solo de customtkinter) en el cual se pueden asociar funciones a ciertos eventos (como los de escritura) con una tupla de este estilo

```
(widget.register(funcion), "cadena que representa un dato especifico del entry que debe pasarse a esta función", ...)
```

`funcion` debe devolver siempre True o False (una lista vacía no cuenta). De lo contrario, el validador se va a desactivar.

En este caso, vamos a usar `validate="key"` para decir que debe activarse cuando el usuario escribe, le vamos a indicar que pase el argumento `"%P"` (que es el texto que tendría el entry si la validación pasara) y haremos que la función devuelva True siempre, ya que, por ahora, no estamos validando al entry realmente y, por lo tanto, toda acción debe considerarse valida.

A continuación tenés el código con una corrección adicional:

```
import customtkinter

marco_ticket = customtkinter.CTk()
marco_ticket.geometry(f"{600}x{300}")
marco_ticket.title("Control de Pesajes Baelca")

#Función validar placa
def validar_placa(texto):
    if len(texto) >=7:
        # tenías State... Lo cambié a state
        entrada.configure(state="normal")
        entrada2.configure(state="normal")
    else:
        pass

    return True
  
                    

label_placa=customtkinter.CTkLabel(marco_ticket, text="Placa :", text_font=("arial", 16))
label_placa.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
entry_placa=customtkinter.CTkEntry(marco_ticket, validate="key", validatecommand=(marco_ticket.register(validar_placa), "%P"))
entry_placa.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, padx=50)
        
        
entrada=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(marco_ticket, values=["Lleno", "Vacio", "Pesada múltiple"], state="disabled")
entrada.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=5, padx=5)
entrada.set("Lleno")

entrada2=customtkinter.CTkEntry(marco_ticket, state="disabled")
entrada2.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=5, padx=5)

validar_placa(entry_placa.get())

marco_ticket.mainloop()
```

Hablé de una forma muuuuy resumida sobre los validadores, ya que en realidad, quiero que se conserve algo de información por si el tutorial cuyo link pienso poner deja de existir.

Este es el link del tutorial: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/validar-el-contenido-de-una-caja-de-texto-en-tkinter/

Comment: Dante, como siempre gracias un millón. El problea está resuelto, ahora a implementarlo en el código fuente.

Comment: De nada Carlos c: